# IRI: What are the differences between and purposes of --rescan and --revalidate?

Tags: iri-node

When we run full nodes (IRI) there are some occasions where we should run java with the flags `--revalidate` and/or `--rescan`.

In which cases should we add those flags and what exactly are the technical differences?

Comment: Can't give a real answer, but [here is where they do something in source](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/f021610fc871efd20325ac8fd602b7a408b985d7/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/Iota.java#L97).

Comment: `--revalidate` was explicitly added to be used after a bug in milestone processing was fixed (it will discard all milestone information and rescan the tangle for milestones). I would not be surprised if that option would disappear (or become a no-op) in the near future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Revalidate** “drops” the stored solid milestone “table”. So all the milestones are revalidated once the node starts (checks signatures, balances etc). This is used it you take a DB from someone else, or have an issue with solid milestones acting out.
>
> **Rescan** drops all the tables, except for the raw transaction trits, and re stores the transactions (refilling the metadata, address indexes etc) - this is used when a migration is needed when the DB schema changes mostly.

Source: http://iri-playbook.readthedocs.io/en/master/faq.html#what-are-the-revalidate-and-rescan-options-for